# Django admin foreign key field cause performance issue

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a `Question` model and a `Solution` model.

```
class Solution(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('exam.Users', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    solution = RichTextField()
```

In Django admin, I display a `Question_text` in `Solution` section.

```
@admin.register(Solution)
class SolutionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_ori_q(self, obj):
        se = obj.question
        return se.question
```

For this `Question_text` field, see the picture below.

[image]

But I don't want to edit it, or make it selectable, for it cost a lot of time to display massive item if I click it.

How can I make it read-only and display only one item, instead of displaying all items in `Question` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
@admin.register(Solution)
class SolutionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('question',)
    def get_ori_q(self, obj):
        se = obj.question
        return se.question
```

Comment: Now the read-only field is in the bottom of the page, is it possible to display the read-only field in the same place before?

Comment: Not an easy code way that I know of. You might have to go and extend the admin template to manually do it.

Comment: Thank you again, I just try to display it using `fieldset`, seems OK.